# Change color in emacs of highlight-indentation package

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting

It says you can use the highlight-indent-face but I'm not sure how to set this variable. Or what to change it to in the *.el. I use a white background so the lines are barely visible. A darker gray or another color would be better. Here is the argument for it:

```
(defface highlight-indent-face
  ;; Fringe has non intrusive color in most color-themes
  '((t :inherit fringe))
  "Basic face for highlighting indentation guides."
  :group 'basic-faces)
```

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face's background can be set by the command `set-face-background`:

```
(set-face-background 'highlight-indent-face "gray80")
```

Comment: Thanks that worked wonderfully. Ended up changing the color and cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification with emacs 24.3 (also with darker gray):

```
set-face-background 'highlight-indentation-face "gray20")
```